# Custom click tracking for adsense

Tags: tracking, adsense

I need to identify my users when an ad is clicked. For example, when user A is online, I need to know that he was the one who clicked the ad unit.

When using my own ads, this was a piece of cake (using URL redirection) - however, now we are planning to switch to Adsense - which renders the Ad via javascript - hence I cannot setup a redirection there.

How do I track - which user which ad unit - in case of adsense?

Thanks alot.

--
Maku

Comment: This will violate terms and conditions of adsense. If you are planning to use adsense as a click to pay system they will kick you.