# How to customize ads tracking of Adsense?

Tags: tracking, adsense, adsense-api

I know my question is relevant to [Custom click tracking for adsense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866332/custom-click-tracking-for-adsense)

but I am here asking it again because I need more answers of above mentioned question. only one answer already there, But it is not what I need. can u people re answer same question again please or answer this question?

Actually I want to show a line chart similar to google analytics showing how many times ads on mysite has been displayed and how many times the ads has been clicked. Can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried this? i have answered on question referenced by you.
my Answer:
Even though there is no good way but it is quite easy to do so. First of all put your adsense code in a div like:

```
<div id="adsDiv" class="adsDiv">
    <!--here your adsense code-->
</div>
```

now in your jquery code use this:

```
$(".adsDiv").on("click", function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        //here call to php function via ajax etc and in php you can easily check which user is currently online via session who clicked on ad.
    }, 5000);
});
```

note your php will function called after 5000 ms which means user has clicked and viewed your ad. you can increase or decrease it as per your need.

Answer (score 1):

You can check your particular click in your report part as like below....[image]

Here you can check the add size 970X250 is clicked 7 times and other are..

Comment: I know this i wana to customize and create my own database.